# cambiar texto mostrado en radio button seleccionado

Tags: javascript

Tengo una función de mostrar valor e index del input seleccionado en un listado type:radio

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var $radBtn = $("span.ef-example-3-rating input:radio");
            $radBtn.click(function() {
                var $radChecked = $(':radio:checked');
                $("#para").text('')
                    .append("<b>Index: </b>" +
                        $radChecked.val() + "<br/>")
                    .append("<b>Value: </b>" +
                        $radChecked.next().text());
            });
        });
    </script>
```

los input son asi

```
<input type="radio" class="ef-example-3-rating-input" id="ef-example-3-rating-input-3-1" name="ef-example-3-rating-input-1" value="hola">
```

y el texto mostrado es el siguiente

> Index: hola
>
> Value:

Yo quisiera que solo aparezca el texto únicamente. Los encabezados no, ni Value ni Index. Quizás también de quererlo así, ¿no tendría que estar el texto en la etiqueta Value: y en Index: un número?

Gracias

Comment: ¿Quieres que no aparezca el "Index:" y sí que aparezca el "Hola"? Si es así, el "encabezado" se lo estás poniendo tú a mano. `.append("<b>Index: </b>" + $radChecked.val() + "<br/>")`. ¿Si quitas lo de "Index" no valdría? `.append($radChecked.val());`

Comment: Hona Hernan, podrias crear un [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) para poder testearlo? creo que no veo todo el codigo o no lo entiendo del todo

Comment: Creo que tal y como te dice @Rabegi , tienes que quitar `"<b>Index: </b>" +` y `"<b>Value: </b>" +`

Comment: Gracias Rabegí. Por ahora me limito a copiar, y modificar por deducción. No entiendo los procesos como los explican en cada paso. Hola,hay dos archivos en el servidor Demos.css
 jquery-1.3.2.min.js.  Ya esta resuelto aplicando lo que indicó Rabegi. Por si te interesa lo copié de http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=402  . Saludos